# How to calculate count of selected checkbox of particular column in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, datatables

My jquery datatable contain one column which has checkbox. i just want to count number of selected checkboxes from that jquery datatable and stor that count value in one variable for further processing.
This is my code to create data table

```
oTable = $("#datatable-assessment-Notes").dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            //  "bSorting": true,
            "aaSorting": [[6, 'asc']],
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                NoteRadioButtonClick();
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                        { "bSortable": false, "sType": "date", "aTargets": [0] },
                        { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [1] },
                        { "aTargets": [2] },
                        { "aTargets": [3] },
                        { "aTargets": [4] },
                        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [5] },
                        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [6] },
                        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, ],
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData) {
                var isViewAll = $("#isview-all").val();
                if (isViewAll == 1) {
                    $(".isviewall").remove();
                    $(".edit_note").remove();
                }
                return nRow;
            }
        });
```

and this is code for checkbox button

```
 <td class="table_heading imp_class_tableData">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.priority, new { @id = "note_priority", @name = "Note_priority_check" })
     </td>
```

Comment: Data-tables has checkbox built-in look [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) and [here](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/)

Comment: Yess it work Perfectly